# d3 transform translate only the second parameter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to select after the initial creation of a g element only the second transform value and modify it?

I want to do something like:

```
d3.select(".class")
    .attr("transform", 'translate(' + _ + ', ' + 0 + ')');
```

Where the first param (the '_') is untouched and only second is modified to 0.

Is this possible after the g class creation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this, the code below shows how I am adding a translate to the g group on clicking of the button: (I have added comments for you to get a better picture of the code)

```js
    //making a g group with in the circle
    var myG = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500).append("g");
    //appending a circle to the g group.
    myG.append("circle").attr("cy", 60).attr("cx", 60).attr("r",10);

    var xTrans = 0;
    d3.select("#click").on("click", function() {
        xTrans+=20;
        //applying transform to g.
     myG.attr("transform", "translate("+xTrans+",0)")
    });
```

```css
circle{
   fill:steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">ClickToAddTransition</button>
```